# Oracle timestein issue (Log Marker) waiting for latch "Log Strand Insertion

Tags: oracle, timesten

I am getting below error while using multiple DS under timetein
ConnId=137 (Log Marker) waiting for latch "Log Strand Insertion[0]"(12345), Holder=1 (c_node) PID 1, now 10 secs

ConnId=135 (Log Marker) waiting for latch "Log Strand Insertion[0]"(12345), Holder=1 (c_node) PID 2, now 10 secs

ConnId=135 (Log Marker) waiting for latch "Log Strand Insertion[0]"(12345), Holder=1 (c_node) PID 2, now 10 secs

ConnId=135 (Log Marker) waiting for latch "Log Strand Insertion[0]"(12345), Holder=1 (c_node) PID 2, now 10 secs

Due to which the system the not able to process efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

We need more context and details that you have provided to give a meaningful answer.

Please log a Service Request with Oracle Support so that you can securely upload the relevant information.

Doug